# How to implement cookies less form authentication when we create our own cookie

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, forms-authentication, security

I am implementing the forms authentication like (I need to create the ticket  based some some conditions not from active directory or from database)

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
        "userName",
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), // value of time out property
        false, // Value of IsPersistent property
        String.Empty,
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(
                            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, 
                            encryptedTicket);

authCookie.Secure = true;
Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

 and my web.config 


<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"
           protection="All"
           timeout="30"
           name="test" 
           path="/"
           requireSSL="false"
           slidingExpiration="true"
          cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"
           enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

This  implementation  is working fine  if the browser cookies are enabled . while  it is not working when  cookies are disabled( I tried Cookieless="useuri" but it doesnt help)

Can you please guys tell me how should i implement  cookiless  forms authentication  in this scenario

I want to use uri   for auth cookie or any other better solution?.

Comment: So you want to use cookies in a cookie-less environment? :S

Comment: store it in session it's a cookie but the cookie resides on the web server

Comment: I would  like to user uri  but it doesnt work   since  i think i am adding  cookie to response object @Ranhiru

Comment: @CBRRacer: It is a cookie :) The data resides in the web server but for the web server to uniquely identify each user cookies must be enabled. Or else going cookieless means having the session id embedded in the URL. Look at the answer given by tugberk.

Comment: @RanhiruCooray actually that was what I was talking about, but I failed to specify the URL aspect of it.

Answer (score 0):

For cookieless browsers asp.net provides session id to embed in URL;

See the below question :

[What will happen to asp.net membership if the client browser is not accepting cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529683/what-will-happen-to-asp-net-membership-if-the-client-browser-is-not-accepting-coo)